# Solve a system of equations depending on a set of parameters with Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equation-solving

Using Mathematica, I want to solve a system of nonlinear equations like

```
f(x,y;m)=0
g(x,y;m)=0
```

where m is an external parameter on which the equations depends on.
As the equations are very hard, what I do is to explicitly fix m, above all, and then find a solution for that specific value of m (by FindRoot[]). But this is very slow and inefficient (and more specifically in my case, where indeed I have three parameters).

What I would like is an automatic method that studies numerically the solution for a discrete set of values ​​for m, that fixes it without that I explicitly change it from time to time. So that I would get all together the solutions for those values ​​of m.

It would be nice also that a similar procedure can be applied to the initial seeds for FindRoot [], since in my case I get several solutions changing the latter, and so there are different solutions for that value of m, and so similarly I would like to have all the solutions for a given set of initial seeds.

Is it possible to do such a thing? How?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, assuming that you have a function solve[m] and a range of values for m={1,2,3,...}, you can use:

```
Map[solve, m]
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "fixing it", but this will give you an array, which you can investigate further.